# playing a video after another one has ended with shockwaveflash player in c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, shockwave

I have a code that takes should take video urls from queue and play next video on the queue after 1 has ended. I just can't get the program to know if the video has ended or not. How can I do this?

This is what I got:

```
{
    if (songrequests.Count > 0)
    {
        var url = songrequests.Dequeue();
        axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Flash movies have no clear concept of "ending".

Comment: @NineBerry Is there a way to get the length of the video from the player or from youtube?

Comment: Youtube has an official API that you can use to query Meta Data about movies https://www.youtube.com/yt/dev/en/api-resources.html